# Is this coding wrong it's not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

The below script inputs data to a database this takes some information from a form then stores them in to the database. And I'm also using uplodify to upload a image file and store the file name in the database but my issue is this data processing script keeps updating the row ID one never jumps to the second line I tried every thing can some one help me with this or show me what I'm doing wrong.

Also this checks the ID and if it's not equal to 1 then does an insertion if it's equal then update it but this not happening.

The ID is auto incrementing.

**My script**

```
<?php

/**
 * @author SiNUX
 * @copyright 2013
 */

include ('connect.php');

$getId = mysql_query("SELECT ID FROM poiinfo ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($getId);

$poiName = $_REQUEST['Name'];
$poiDes = $_REQUEST['Descrip'];
$poiCon = $_REQUEST['ConInfo'];
//$poiId = $_REQUEST['pID'];

if($row['ID'] != "1"){
    $dbData = "INSERT INTO poiinfo(`Name`, `Des.`, `Contact`) VALUES ('$poiName','$poiDes','$poiCon')";        
    $putData = mysql_query($dbData);

    if ($putData){
        echo "Data inserted";
    }else {
        echo "Not Done";
    }

}else {
    $updLn = "UPDATE `poiinfo` SET `Name`='$poiName',`Des.`='$poiDes',`Contact`='$poiCon'";
    $updDone = mysql_query($updLn);

    if ($updDone){
        echo "Data inserted";
    }else {
        echo "Not Done";
    }
 }       
?>
```

I tried u r suggestions but it's still the same now my code for the update is looks like this.

```
$updLn = "UPDATE `poiinfo` SET `Name`='$poiName',`Des.`='$poiDes',`Contact`='$poiCon' WHERE `ID`='".$row['ID']."'";
```

But still it keeps up dating the ID 1 not moving on to the next one.

Comment: And exact problem or question?

Comment: What the subject says ? use proper subject

Comment: It's problem this code which I've written it's keep updating the same data row I want it to move to the next step.

Answer (score 0):

Your update query is missing a WHERE clause. Try this:

```
$updLn = "UPDATE `poiinfo` SET `Name`='$poiName',`Des.`='$poiDes',`Contact`='$poiCon' WHERE ID = '".$row['ID']."'";
```

Also be beware of MySQL Injections: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I tried this but still that problem is there what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $updLn = "UPDATE `poiinfo` SET `Name`='$poiName',`Des.`='$poiDes',`Contact`='$poiCon'";
```

You need a where clause in this sql to specify a record to update. Currently it is updating all records.

```
    $updLn = "UPDATE `poiinfo` SET `Name`='$poiName',`Des.`='$poiDes',`Contact`='$poiCon' WHERE `ID` = ".$row['id']";";
```

You will need to set an $id variable for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

To check why your update failed, you should call `mysql_error` in your last `else` clause :

```
} else {
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

As for the first problem : if you never insert a new record (I don't see how that could happen, provided your code), you will never have a record whose ID is 2.

Comment: same issue I did check for errors by echo but no error comes out also ID 1 is there and it's keep getting updated with out going to 2